# I am stuck at the process of retrieving a value from a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I am stuck at the process of retrieving a value from a matrix. I am using a MatLab program as reference. 
for example. `delv(2,k) = dell{2,K}(1,1)`. 
Which mean, the value of `delv(2,k)` is the value from the 1st column and 1st row of matrix `dell{2,K}`. 
I'm using `np.matrix` and I'm stuck in retrieving the value for 1st row 1st column from `dell(2,k)`.

```
def ww(j,k):
    return npy.matrix.I(alfa(j,k))*(rr(j,k)-(BJ(j,k)*ww(j-1,k)))

def dell(j,k):
     if j == np:
        return ww(np,k)
     else:   
        return ww(j,k) - (gamma(j,k)*dell(j+1,k))
def delf(j,k):
    if j == 1:
        return 0
    elif j == 2:
        # This should be returning the 2nd row 1st column value of dell(2,k)
        return dell(2,k) (2,1) 
    else:
        return dell(j,k)
def delu(j,k):
    if j == 1 or j == np:
        return 0
    elif j == np-1:
        return dell(j,k)
def delv(j,k):
    if j == 1:
        return dell(2,k)
    elif j == 2:
        return dell(2,k)
    else:
        return dell(j,k)
```

Comment: In Python you access items using `[]`, not `()`.  You should read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to familiarize yourself with the basics of Python.

Comment: You're also going to want to read [NumPy for MATLAB users](http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users): there are some other pitfalls you're going to hit immediately.  For example, Python is 0-indexed, not 1-indexed (the first element in a `numpy` array is `x[0]`, not `x[1]`), so I think many of these functions are now off by one.

Comment: sry for the slack of information and knowledge that i have. this is my first time using python. does that mean that matrix value i should retrieve should be in []?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
return dell(2,k) (2,1)
```

You should use:

```
return dell(2, k)[1,1]
```

The difference being that you should use `[]` instead of `()` to get the `[row, col]` value of an array or matrix. Note that `[1,1]` is actually the *second* row and *second* column:

```
In [201]: a = npy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

In [202]: a
Out[202]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

In [203]: a[1,1]
Out[203]: 4

In [204]: a[0,0]
Out[204]: 1

In [205]: a[0,1]
Out[205]: 2
```

You can access an entire row or col as such:

```
# the first row
In [206]: a[0]
Out[206]: array([1, 2])

# the second row
In [207]: a[1]
Out[207]: array([3, 4])

# the second column
In [208]: a[:,1]         # the : gives all rows here, the 1 gets second column
Out[208]: array([2, 4])

# the first row again, using a `:` even though it's not required
In [209]: a[0,:]         # here the : gives all columns (it can be left off as in line 206)
Out[209]: array([1, 2])
```